# Sql query, table /w double rows, join on IFNULL function - table join on tiself with variable column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, ifnull

Hi we have a table that looks like this (call it table A). It contains both rows if parent and children data. I need to get rows like below containing both the item_id and the parent_item_id if it exists (otherwise the item_id). Now I need to join on the

`item_id (if parent) + parent_item_id as new_id`
and
`item_id (if no parent) + item_id as new_id`

I have used the `IFNULL` function like this `IFNULL(parent_item_id, item_id) as new_id` and then later I use `new_id` to join on the same table A again against item_id to get some final values

To make a long story short, my query is

```
select item_id, IFNULL(parent_item_id, item_id) AS new_id 
from table A as A1
INNER JOIN table A as A2 ON A1.new_id = A2.item_id 
where A1.type = simple
```

The problem is that I don't seem to be allowed to join on the same table again using my newly created column `new_id`

**QUESTION:** how do I rephrase this query so my join is allowed? or is there a smarter way to go altogether to get this done?

**Data example**

```
|--item_id --|--parent_item_id--|---type---|--price--|
   123          124               simple     0.00
   124          null              config     9.00
   125          null              simple     8.00
```

I need to join this table A on itself on a variabel column

Error is

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'new_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: change **INNER JOIN table A as A2 ON A1.new_id = A2.item_id ** to **INNER JOIN table A as A2 ON IFNULL(A1.parent_item_id, A1.item_id) = A2.item_id **

Comment: This is it! Please submit as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the calculation direct into the **INNER JOIN** like this :

```
select item_id, IFNULL(parent_item_id, item_id) AS new_id 
from table A as A1
INNER JOIN table A as A2 ON IFNULL(A1.parent_item_id, A1.item_id) = A2.item_id 
where A1.type = simple
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A as A2 
JOIN
(
select item_id, type, IFNULL(parent_item_id, item_id)  AS new_id from  A
)A1
ON (A1.new_id = A2.item_id)
where A1.type = 'simple'
```